# AngularJS: 401 - Unauthorized: HttpInterceptor with Basic Auth

Tags: angularjs, basic-authentication

I want to call a Rest-Service (Spring MVC) to receive a list of releases. On client side (AngularJs) I use a service creating a HttpClient call. I also have a registered HttpInterceptor to use simple Basic Authentification. The interceptor is provided in app.modules.ts and **is called during the rest call**.

Unfortunately I get statuscode 401 and I cannot find the 'Authentification' entry in the header. What is missing?

Interceptor:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpRequest, HttpHandler, HttpEvent, HttpInterceptor } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';

@Injectable()
export class BasicAuthInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {


  intercept(request: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {

  request = request.clone({
    setHeaders: {
      Authorization: `Basic username:password`
    },
  }); 


  return next.handle(request);
  }
}
```

Service class:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Observable, of } from 'rxjs/';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { catchError, map, tap } from 'rxjs/operators';
import { Release } from './Release';

@Injectable()
export class ReleasesService {

  constructor(
    private http: HttpClient) {}

  private releasesUrl = 'http://localhost:8080/releases/showAll';

  getReleases(): Observable<Release[]> {
    return this.http
      .get<Release[]>(this.releasesUrl)
      .pipe( tap(releases => this.log('fetched releases')),
         catchError(this.handleError('getReleases', [])));
  }

  private handleError<T> (operation = 'operation', result?: T) {
    return (error: any): Observable<T> => {
      console.error(error); // log to console instead
      return of(result as T);
   };
  }

  private log(message: string) {
    console.info(message);
  }
}
```

app.modules.ts

```
  providers: [
      APP_PROVIDERS,
     { provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS, useClass: BasicAuthInterceptor, multi: true },
  ],
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution.

Setting the header was correct. But I had to add following parameter to the HttpClient-call: **{ withCredentials: true }**

```
getReleases(): Observable<Release[]> {
return this.http
  .get<Release[]>(this.releasesUrl, { withCredentials: true })
  .pipe( tap(releases => this.log('fetched releases')),
     catchError(this.handleError('getReleases', [])));
```

}

Then the credentials are passed to the server.